# What is the name of CMake's default build target?

Tags: c++, c, build, cmake

I have a custom target, and I want it to depend on the default target (the one that is built with `make`).

```
add_custom_target(foo ....)
add_dependency(foo default_target_name_goes_here)
```

What is the name of the default target?

I've tried `ALL`, `ALL_BUILD`, `MyProjectsName`, `DEFAULT`,...

Finding anything in the CMake documentation is always an unsuccessful adventure...

UPDATE: it seems CMake was designed in such a way that this is extremely hard to fix/implement: [bugreport getting +1's since 2009](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=8438). Who indeed would like to have a custom target that depends on, for example, the `all` target? Or in other words: who does ever write `make && make test`?...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [default build target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/user-interaction/index.html#selecting-a-target) is named `all` or `ALL_TARGET`.

The default build target does not exist as a CMake target at CMake configure time. It is only exists in the generated build system. Therefore it is not possible to have the default target depend on a custom target.

Comment: "use the ALL option": this adds my target to ALL. I want to add ALL to my target as a dependency. This cannot be done. There is a bugreport/feature request from 2009 here: http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=8438

Comment: Rephrase your question to "I want the default target to depend on it".

Comment: What is unclear in the first sentence of my question: "I have a custom target, and I want it to depend on the default target " ?

Comment: I read it as "I want it (my custom target) to depend on the default target". That is different to "I want the default target to depend on my custom target".

Comment: Your reading was correct. What ALL does is add a custom target to the `ALL` target, so that when you build the ALL target, that custom target is also built. I do not want this. I want the `ALL` target to be built when I write `make my_target`. That is: I want `make my_target` to be equivalent to `make && make my_target`.

Answer (score 1):

I think a possible solution depends strongly on the use case. E.g. if this is for executing a test after the system has been build you would use `CTest` instead of calling `make` directly.

To your CMakeLists.txt you would add:

```
 add_test(NAME foo COMMAND ...)
```

and then use `CTest` for building and executing:

```
 ctest --build-and-test ...
```

More generally speaking and not considering the question of why you would like to do it - I think the best thing would be to just name and rely on concrete target dependencies instead of just taking `ALL` targets - I just wanted to add two possibilities to do what you wanted to do.

One would be to determine/track the list of all targets used as discussed [here](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-September/039388.html). This would look e.g. for library targets like this (getting your own/private `GlobalTargetList`):

```
macro(add_library _target)
    _add_library(${_target} ${ARGN})
    set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY GlobalTargetList ${_target})
endmacro()
```

and use it at the end of your main CMakeLists.txt with

```
get_property(_allTargets GLOBAL PROPERTY GlobalTargetList)
add_dependencies(foo ${_allTargets})
```

**Edit:** Global [`BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS.html#prop_dir:BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS) property was released with CMake 3.7

The second - less favorable - approach does require that the `foo` target is not part of the `ALL` build (otherwise you end-up in an endless loop):

```
add_custom_target(foo)
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL 1) 

add_custom_command(
    TARGET foo
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target ALL_BUILD --config $<CONFIGURATION>
)
```

Comment: CMake likes to put everything into the ALL target by default (e.g. external projects). Building anything generally requires building the ALL target first: I'd rather write `make tests` instead of `make && make tests`. This problem gets worse as the number of targets increases.  User-defined targets cannot depend on any of the builtin targets: ALL, INSTALL, ... The "simplest" solution I found is to collect anything added to ALL into different targets, and then add dependencies to these. Not as comfortable, but works.

Comment: If you are refering to the `include_external_msproject()` command, I admit I have patched my CMake 2.8.10 version to default the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` property to `TRUE` (see `cmIncludeExternalMSProjectCommand.cxx`). And I generally prefer to have the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` set to `TRUE` (e.g. via the corresponding directory property). That allows in an complex build environment to selectivly compile only specific targets and their dependencies. But when I have setup the cross-target depencies correctly, it works for me just fine (including make enviroments using parallel build engines).

Comment: Actually I was referring to "ExternalProject_Add", but yes, `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` is a better default :)