# Making all projects in CMake Visual Studio depend on one project

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

In my project, I have about 250 projects with one main project that uses most of the projects. It's important that all projects are up to date when the main project is run. So basically, Visual Studio should check for all 250 projects for changes when MainProject is compiled (and run). My CMakeLists.txt files look like this.

**Root/CMakeLists.txt**

```
....
add_subdirectory (MainProject)
add_subdirectory (ProjectA)
add_subdirectory (ProjectB)
add_subdirectory (ProjectC)
add_subdirectory (ProjectD)
....
```

**Root/MainProject/CMakeLists.txt**

```
....
add_executable (MainProject a.cpp b.cpp)
add_dependencies (MainProject ProjectA ProjectB ...)
....
```

**Root/ProjectA/CMakeLists.txt**

```
....
add_executable (ProjectA a.cpp b.cpp)
....
```

Obviously this is a very simplified example, but hopefully the idea is there. Basically, in order to make Visual Studio to check for dependencies for all 250 projects or so, I have to add all the other projects in the main project as dependencies. Now this is not an elegant solution at all, as add_dependencies in MainProject has a LOT of dependencies in it. It works, but is there anything more elegant for this problem?

Comment: Are the other projects libraries to be included in the `MainProject`? Or do you want to have all libraries, executables and custom targets linked to main?

Comment: The latter. I want all libraries, executables and custom targets to be checked (i.e. linked to main as dependency) when the MainProject is run.

Comment: Then please see my answer with possible solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532448/what-is-the-name-of-cmakes-default-build-target/30575893#30575893). In your case most probably overwriting `add_executable()`, `add_library()` and `add_custom_target()` would do the trick. At the moment (as per CMake version 3.5.x), there is as far as I know no global target list provided by CMake itself.

Comment: Ah, that is a shame, but overwriting sounds adequate for my problem.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend redefining existing functions, instead define your own, say `my_add_library` so that it's clear that something magical happens.

Comment: How does the executable depend on these projects? I was under the impression that CMake adds linked-in libraries automatically as dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

At the moment (as per CMake version 3.5.x), there is - as far as I know - no global target list provided by CMake itself (e.g. as a global property).

**Edit:** It is now implemented: Global [`BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS.html#prop_dir:BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS) property was released with CMake 3.7

**Posible Solutions**

1. In your case - going by the assumption that you don't want to modify all 250 sub-project's `CMakeLists.txt` files - overwriting `add_executable()`, `add_library()` and `add_custom_target()` would do the trick:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

   project(DependsAllTest)

   macro(add_library _target)
       _add_library(${_target} ${ARGN})
       set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY GlobalTargetList ${_target})
   endmacro()

   macro(add_executable _target)
       _add_executable(${_target} ${ARGN})
       set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY GlobalTargetList ${_target})
   endmacro()

   macro(add_custom_target _target)
       _add_custom_target(${_target} ${ARGN})
       set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY GlobalTargetList ${_target})
   endmacro()

   add_subdirectory(MainProject)
   add_subdirectory(ProjectA)
   add_subdirectory(ProjectB)
   add_subdirectory(ProjectC)
   add_subdirectory(ProjectD)

   get_property(_allTargets GLOBAL PROPERTY GlobalTargetList)
   message(STATUS "GlobalTargetList: ${_allTargets}")
   add_dependencies(MainProject ${_allTargets})
   ```

   Sure enough, if you would do this from scratch I would - as @Lindydancer has suggested - use your own versions of those commands to allow global customizations.
2. If you go by the prerequisite that `MainProject` is always first, you could simplify this a little:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

   project(DependsAllTest2)

   macro(add_library _target)
       _add_library(${_target} ${ARGN})
       add_dependencies(MainProject ${_target})
   endmacro()

   macro(add_executable _target)
       _add_executable(${_target} ${ARGN})
       add_dependencies(MainProject ${_target})
   endmacro()

   macro(add_custom_target _target)
       _add_custom_target(${_target} ${ARGN})
       add_dependencies(MainProject ${_target})
   endmacro()

   add_subdirectory(MainProject)
   add_subdirectory(ProjectA)
   add_subdirectory(ProjectB)
   add_subdirectory(ProjectC)
   add_subdirectory(ProjectD)
   ```

**References**

- [CMake: Getting a list of all targets?](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-September/039388.html)
- [What is the name of CMake's default build target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532448/what-is-the-name-of-cmakes-default-build-target)