# CMake : Compile only one subdirectory with preset

Tags: cmake, preset

I have a project with this structure, where Components are subdirectories :

```
CMakeList.txt
CMakePresets.json
|
---Component1/CMakeList.txt
|
---Component2/CMakeList.txt
|
---Component3/CMakeList.txt
```

I would like to compile only Component1 with the root preset. (I mean compile all targets under Component1).

Normally, to configure and compile all the project i use this commands :

```
#Configuration
cd myBuildDir
cmake mySourcedDir --preset=myPreset
#Compilation
cd mySourcedDir 
cmake --build --preset=myPreset
```

Problems :

- With ninja, after configuration, the myBuildDir/Component1 directory doesn't contain build.ninja file
- If i try to do `cmake --build` in the mySourcedDir/Component1 directory, i have an error message : `CMake Error: Could not read presets from...`

Comment: Soo `cmake --build --preset=myPreset --target component1`?

Comment: it doesn't work because component1 is a subdirectory and not a target : ```ninja: error: unknown target component1```

Comment: Then pick a target from the subdirectory? Edit Component1/CMakeList.txt , add a Component1 target that has all the targets from that file, and then compile.

Comment: How do you do a target which contains other targets ? by doing a target_link_libraries ?

Comment: Something along `add_custom_target(Component1 DEPENDS target1 target2 etc)`. I also found out https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing Component1/CMakeList.txt with:

```
get_property(ALL_BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS DIRECTORY PROPERTY BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS)
add_custom_target(Component1 DEPENDS ${ALL_BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS})
```

And then do:

```
cmake --build --preset=myPreset --target component1
```

Comment: Thanks, the BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS is not yet a GLOBAL PROPERTY, we can only use it like a DIRECTORY PROPERTY, but by using function and macros i can have my solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62311397/7079226