# How to list all the targets in CMake's default (`all`) targets?

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to display all the targets that are included in CMake's default target?

I tried browsing all the CMakeLists.txt of my project by hand, but it is very tedious as there are many of them.

Comment: You may iterate over **all targets**, using e.g. [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62311397/3440745), and include only those targets, which have property [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL.html) being false-evaluated.