# cmake: get add_library() names

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to get the names of all `add_library()` calls? E.g.

```
add_library(lib1
  some.cpp
)

add_library(lib2
  some.cpp
)

add_library(lib3
  some.cpp
)

# And then somehow get in a variable MY_LIBRARIES_NAMES = lib1 lib2 lib3
```

Is there any cmake call or variable that does that? (I am interested in cmake version 2.8 if it matters)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of CMake (>= version 3.7) that would be the [`BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS.html) directory property:

```perl
get_directory_property(MY_LIBRARIES_NAMES BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS)
```

For older versions of CMake you could overwrite the `add_library()` call to collect a list of targets:

```perl
macro(add_library _target)
    _add_library(${_target} ${ARGN})
    set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY GlobalTargetList ${_target})
endmacro()

...

get_property(_allTargets GLOBAL PROPERTY GlobalTargetList)
message(STATUS "GlobalTargetList: ${_allTargets}")
```

**References**

- [Making all projects in CMake Visual Studio depend on one project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333310/making-all-projects-in-cmake-visual-studio-depend-on-one-project)
- [CMake: How do I change properties on subdirectory project targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092198/cmake-how-do-i-change-properties-on-subdirectory-project-targets)