# In CMake, how to make the test target depend on the default (all) target?

Tags: cmake, build-dependencies

I've enabled testing in CMake as follows:

```
# ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(hello-world VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES C CXX)

enable_testing()
...
```

...and I've added tests like this:

```
# /home/user/path/to/my/project/src/test/CMakeLists.txt
set(TEST_FILES test.cpp)

add_executable(my-test ${TEST_FILES})

add_test(NAME my-test
  COMMAND my-test --gtest_output=xml:${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/TestResult/my-test.xml
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

(I *think* that the method of adding tests is not relevant to the question, but please let me know if otherwise; this method for adding tests is per instruction from the Udemy course from which I learned CMake)

With the above, it seems necessary to build the default target (`all`) first before building the test target. I.e. I cannot do this:

```
$ cmake --build --preset linux --target test
Running tests...
    Start 1: my-test
Could not find executable /home/user/path/to/my/project/src/test/my-test
Looked in the following places:
...
```

...I need to do this:

```
$ cmake --build --preset linux
$ cmake --build --preset linux --target test # this now succeeds
```

**Is there a way to make the `test` target depend on the default (`all`) target?**

Per [this CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/user-interaction/index.html#selecting-a-target), my understanding is that `test` is not a custom target, i.e. it's not something I explicitly added with a `add_custom_target()`. Nevertheless, from articles like this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532448/what-is-the-name-of-cmakes-default-build-target) and [the CMake documentation on `add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html), I thought the solution would be adding something like:

```
add_dependencies(test all)
```

to the top-level CMakeLists.txt, but that resulted in this error:

```
$ cmake --preset linux
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (add_dependencies):
  Cannot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target "test".

  The add_dependencies works for top-level logical targets created by the
  add_executable, add_library, or add_custom_target commands.  If you want to
  add file-level dependencies see the DEPENDS option of the add_custom_target
  and add_custom_command commands.
```

I don't think I'm adding file-level dependencies, so I don't think the error message's suggestion is helpful.

Comment: You can't. The default targets aren't accessible as buildsystem targets during the configure/generate steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [workflow preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#workflow-preset) where can combine configuration, build, and run test presets. So your CLI gonna look like this:

```
cmake --workflow --preset do-everything
```